# Can we create a electric field without actually using a battery or power source?

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-fields, charge, ions

Can we create an electric field without actually using a battery or a source of electricity? Like a take 2 panels, one is positively charged and another is negatively charged and put them parallel to each other. Will it create a electric field? Thanks.
Regards,
Bhavesh

Comment: You just need charges and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single charged object is sufficient to produce an electric field. Following Coulomb's law: 
$\textbf{E} = {Q \over 4\pi \epsilon_0\textbf{r}^2}\hat{\textbf{r}}$
where $\textbf{E}$ is the vector electric field, Q the charge of the object in question, $\epsilon_0$ the permittivity of vacuum or the electric constant, $\textbf{r}$ the vector position of the point in question relative to the charged object in question.
This equation shows that any point charge can produce an electric field. Therefore, a single charged object is sufficient to create an electric field, not two. Of course, plates are not point charges, but the same applies, as long as the electric field doesn't cancel itself out (such as within a hollow sphere that has a uniformly charged shell).

Comment: but if a take two charged panels one positevly and another negatively to control the movement of electrons the two charged bodies will create a stronger electric field right?

Comment: @Bhavesh The positive charge is sufficient to control the movement of electrons. It is indeed true that the electric field will be stronger though, because then the total field strength would be the sum of two vectors, one has a positive magnitude towards a certain direction and the other one has a "negative magnitude towards the opposite direction"$\equiv$"positive magnitude towards the same direction"

Comment: A number of comments not relating to this post have been deleted.